# Regex Finds a number behind a text phase

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that is a ContentStream of an email object.

The string is like "....Number of apples:\t1000...."

I need to get 1000 into a variable. But I'm unable to build a RegEx that works.

I need some help.

Comment: You should post the regex that you tried.

Comment: Do you need to find any kind of number, e.g. any decimal or just integers?

Comment: Will it always start with 'Number of apples:' ?? what's stopping you just using a simple search (whether using regex or not) and just using Substring to get the numeric part. You can use regex groups to close the \d+ part of the regex, then access this group from the regex result. This does smell a little bit like homework though !!

Comment: wow actually this morning i figured it out that a simple search would do it. thanks for quick replies. i guess my head was too tired last night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\d+` for non-negative integers. `\-?\d+` for positive or negative integers.

That will, of course, match *any* number in your string. You should include some lookaround to ensure that you capture the correct number. For the above example:

```
@"(?<=Number\ of\ apples\:\s*)\d+"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something like this as a base for your experiments:

```
\b(-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)\b
```

Comment: If the number is negative, the regex will match only if the `-` immediately follows a word because of the first `\b`.

Comment: There is a space between "-" and the digits in some languages (- 1000). Anyway you can´t have -1000 apples :)

Comment: @OndraMorský: unless you owe someone a really substantial apple pie!

Comment: ah there's no negative number in here i guess, unless they want to give me apples instead of asking me for some.